# How to show AlertDialog as permission rationale

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-permissions

I have two activities: a `Main`, as well a `RuntimePermissionManager`, which is started first whenever my app is opened.

The app works as expected when the user allows the runtime permission, but when they deny it, instead of the `AlertDialog` showing up with the permission rationale, the permission dialog is closed completely, and I just get an infinite splash screen (since I have set it to always be on screen during the lifetime of its parent activity).

I have copied the permission logic straight from the `RuntimePermissionsBasic` example bundled with Android Studio, and just replaced the `Snackbar` with an `AlertDialog`, so I don’t see why my app isn’t working.

Here’s the complete `RuntimePermissionManager` activity for reference.

Thanks.

```
public class RuntimePermissionManager extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private static final String TAG = "RuntimePermissionManager";
    private static final String PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    private static final int PERMISSION_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // This ensures no hiccups while the splash screen is active.
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition(() -> true);
        checkRuntimePermissionStatus();
        ThreadManager.unpackCriticalAssets(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Runtime permission has been granted.");
                startMainActivity();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Runtime permission has been denied.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkRuntimePermissionStatus() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Runtime permission has been granted.");
            startMainActivity();
        } else {
            requestRuntimePermission();
        }
    }

    private void requestRuntimePermission() {
        System.out.println(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, PERMISSION));
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, PERMISSION)) {
            System.out.println("HERE1");
            showPermissionRationaleDialog(R.string.permission_rationale_title, R.string.permission_rationale_message);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Runtime permission has been denied.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{PERMISSION}, PERMISSION_ID);
        }
    }

    private void showPermissionRationaleDialog(final int title, final int message) {
        System.out.println("HERE2");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RuntimePermissionManager.this);
        builder.setTitle(title).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RuntimePermissionManager.this, new String[]{PERMISSION}, PERMISSION_ID);
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```